# What is the equivalent to magit pull with rebase flag using fetch instead?

Tags: git, emacs, git-rebase, magit

In magit I often use `F -r u` to pull and rebase my commits on top of the latest from origin. The inefficient part for me when I do this is I often go to the GitHub first to actually see what’s new before pulling. To avoid that step I used fetch instead `f u` and that gives me an unpulled section in the status buffer. I merged it with `m i` for “merge into” my HEAD but this unfortunately wasn’t the same and made the history nonlinear locally which I had to fix. How should I have / do I achieve the same result as the `F -r u` if I first fetch instead?